# Finding the intersection of a list of dictionaries based on an arbitrary field

Tags: python, list, dictionary, intersection

Say I have a list of dictionaries `l1` and `l2`. Each contains dictionaries of the same format. I'd like to find the intersection of `l1` and `l2` based on some field of the dictionary.

For example, let

```
l1 = [{"key":1, "key2":2}, {"key":1, "key2":0}],
l2 = [{"key":0, "key2":2}].
```

I'd like to intersect them based on "key2".
So, `l1.intersect(l2) = 2`.

I can do this as follows which has the complexity of O(len(l1) + len(l2)) if I'm not mistaken.

```
d = defaultdict(bool)
for e in l2:
    d[e['key2']] = True
intersection=set()
for e in l1:
    if d[e['key2']]:
        intersection.add(e['key2])
```

What I wonder is if there exists a better solution or if my solution is already optimal.

Comment: Your dictionary names don't make a lot of sense. A dictionary is a set of key: value pairs. So you've named one key "key" and the other key "value".

Comment: This is just a simplified example. The dictionary can contain an arbitrary number of fields.

Comment: what if in the second dict will `"key": 1`

Comment: It's a very confusing example and suggests you don't fully understand what you're written, and confuses people trying to read it. If you think it makes sense I would suggest changing it to {"key1": 1, "key2": 2} or something.

Comment: You're correct. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: Why use a `defaultdict(bool)` instead of a set?

Comment: @PM 2Ring What difference would using sets make?

Comment: you have to check all values since those are lists of dicts. So you could micro-optimize but the complexity cannot be reduced with such a dataset

Comment: Do all the dicts in the lists have the same keys? If so, it may be a good idea to use named tuples instead of dicts to save on RAM, especially if the lists are large.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you're trying to code. Can you give a general description, and some more examples of input and output including edge cases?

Comment: A set uses less RAM than a dict. OTOH, in Python 3.6+ a dict retains insertion order, which may be useful, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: @PM 2Ring so you suggest I should add from l1 to a set and then iterate over l2 and check if elements are in the set, right?

Comment: Exactly. It probably won't be faster, but will use less RAM, and saves having to import defaultdict. But the main reason to use a set here is a style & design issue. It's almost always better to use one of the standard built-in types if it does the job, rather than a fancier object that has features that you don't really need.

Comment: On second thoughts, it's probably more efficient to use set operations on those values to perform the intersection. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this compact by using set comprehensions. For example,

```
l1 = [{"key":1, "key2":2}, {"key":3, "key2":4}, {"key":5, "key2":6}, {"key":7, "key2":8}]
l2 = [{"key":0, "key2":2}, {"key":1, "key2":3}, {"key":2, "key2":4}]

key = "key2"
values = {d[key] for d in l1} & {d[key] for d in l2}
print(values)
```

**output**

```
{2, 4}
```

---

You can make the code a little more readable by doing the set comprehension in a function, although the function calls will make the code microscopically slower.

```
def key_set(seq, key):
    return {d[key] for d in seq}

values = key_set(l1, key) & key_set(l2, key)
```

This technique can be generalised to handle any number of lists.

```
all_lists = (l1, l2)
key = "key2"
values = set.intersection(*({d[key] for d in seq} for seq in all_lists))
```

Comment: But doesn't it take a bit more time in your example? so we first fetch values from l1 and then from l2. this is already len(l1) + len(l2). After that we do the set intersection.

Comment: @SpiderRico True, and that makes the time complexity O(len(l1) + len(l2)) + O(min(len(l1), len(l2)), which is still O(len(l1) + len(l2)). However, the set comprehensions are pretty fast, and more importantly, the intersection operation is done at C speed, which is significantly faster than your Python loop with an `if` test.